# SSL on subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to configure a wildcard SSL certificate to serve on subdomains as well as on the main domain for a server. In order to get the SSL cert to work, it seems that I must define the main site's sites-available file as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

When I try to use `<VirtualHost someSite.com:443>` then Firefox complains:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.someSite.com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

Google Chrome is less specific:

```
SSL connection error
```

**To what could I change `<VirtualHost *:443>` so that I could serve sub.someSite.com as a different Virtual Host with SSL as well?**

This is on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (3.2 kernel) with Apache 2.2.22 and a Godaddy SSL certificate.

**Edit:**: Here is the [Apache sites-enabled file for the domain](http://pastebin.com/GMTVJAJD).

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
#<VirtualHost *:443>           # With this line, the site serves fine
<VirtualHost someSite.com:443> # With this line, browsers throw the error
        DocumentRoot /var/www/someSite/public_html

        ServerName someSite.com
        ServerAlias www.someSite.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/someSite/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/someSite.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/someSite.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: paste configuration file of apache, ssl virtualhost

Comment: @B14D3: Thanks, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache recommends against](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) using a hostname in the `<VirtualHost>` directive for a [variety of reasons](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dns-caveats.html).

The best practice is to specify the IP address or `*` in `<VirtualHost>` and the hostname(s) of the virtual host in the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives.

So to resolve this:

- If you want all of the wildcard subdomains to be served by the existing virtual host, add `ServerAlias *.example.com` to it.
- If you want all the wildcard subdomains to be served by a completely different virtual host, add a new `<VirtualHost>` block with a `ServerName something.example.com` and `ServerAlias *.example.com`.

Comment: For posterity: I had to add `NameVirtualHost *:443` to `ports.conf` as well.